# How do I use two boolean values in a while loop, for example, while A and B is true

Tags: python

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to make a 2-player dice rolling game. I set a value for player_a and player_b to be false initially. But when i try to but them together in a while loop in one line, the code doesn't seem to work. Here is the code, I still have to work on a couple of things so...

```
import random
import time

player_a = input("Player1, please type your name:")
time.sleep(1)
player_b = input("Player2, please type your name:")
time.sleep(1)
print("Welcome to Dice Roller", player_a, "and", player_b)

score_a = 0
score_b = 0
roll_a = False
roll_b = False

while roll_a and roll_b is False:      #what is the problem with this line because without this, i'm 
                                     not ablee to reset the turn and the end 
                                   
ans_a = input("Type roll to roll the dice:")
    if ans_a == "roll":
        roll_a = (random.randint(1, 6))
        time.sleep(1)
        print(player_a, "has rolled", roll_a)
    else:
        print("Please check your spelling")
    time.sleep(1)
    ans_b = input("Your turn to roll, type roll to roll the dice:")
    if ans_b == "roll":
        roll_b = (random.randint(1, 6))
        time.sleep(1)
        print(player_b, "has rolled", roll_b)
    if roll_a == roll_b:
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Tie")
    if roll_a > roll_b:
        score_a = roll_a - roll_b
        print(player_a, "has scored", score_a, "points")
    if roll_b > roll_a:
        score_b = roll_b - roll_a
        print(player_b, "has scored", score_b, "points")
        break
    roll_a = False
    roll_b = False
```

Comment: You need to re-write the condition for the while loop: `while not all(roll_a, roll_b):` or, alternatively it can also be done as `while not roll_a and not roll_b:`, but the former version is cleaner.

Comment: @pavel Those two are not logically equivalent.

Comment: @kaya3, yep, thanks.... Yeah, the fist version is not going to fly.

Answer (score 1):

You've written:

```
while roll_a and roll_b is False:
```

which is the same as all of the following:

```
while (roll_a is True) and (roll_b is False):
while roll_a is True and roll_b is False:
while (roll_a) and (not roll_b):
while roll_a and not roll_b:
```

You mean to write any of the following (they are all equivalent):

```
while (roll_a is False) and (roll_b is False):
while roll_a is False and roll_b is False:
while (not roll_a) and (not roll_b):
while not roll_a and not roll_b:
```

Comment: Oh right i don't know why i didn't bother writing it out like that haha. Thanks for the help anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
while roll_a is False and roll_b is False:
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while loop` seems ok, but problems seem in `roll_a` and `roll_b` variables. You have initialized these two variables to `False` which is `boolean` type, but later on, you are assigning numbers to these variables inside `while` loop!!. You could store scores from rolls in `score_a` and `score_b` variables.

If the concept is the game will continue until anyone win, see the below code.

```
import random
import time

player_a = input("Player1, please type your name:")
time.sleep(1)
player_b = input("Player2, please type your name:")
time.sleep(1)
print("Welcome to Dice Roller", player_a, "and", player_b)

score_a = 0
score_b = 0
roll_a = False
roll_b = False

while roll_a is False and roll_b is False:

    ans_a = input("{}, type roll to roll the dice:".format(player_a))
    if ans_a == "roll":
        score_a = (random.randint(1, 6))
        time.sleep(1)
        print(player_a, "has rolled", score_a)
    else:
        print("Please check your spelling")
    time.sleep(1)
    ans_b = input("{}, your turn to roll, type roll to roll the dice:".format(player_b))
    if ans_b == "roll":
        score_b = (random.randint(1, 6))
        time.sleep(1)
        print(player_b, "has rolled", score_b)
    if score_a == score_b:
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Tie!!..")
    if score_a > score_b:
        score_a = score_a - score_b
        print(player_a, "has won with ", score_a, "points")
        roll_a = True
    if score_b > score_a:
        score_b = score_b - score_a
        print(player_b, "has won with ", score_b, "points")
        roll_b = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why no one gave this simple answer:

`while roll_a and roll_b is False:`, just enclose the conditions in `()` to make them one entity like this:

`while (roll_a and roll_b) is False:`

or better still

`while not (roll_a and roll_b):`